# Why the javascript alert not displaying inside UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I have a linkbutton inside an updatepanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="upSaveComplete" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel90" runat="server" CssClass="navInnerDiv" Width="200px" ClientIDMode="Static">
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel91" runat="server" CssClass="navInnerDivContents">
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel92" runat="server" CssClass="navInnerDivContentsTop">
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel93" runat="server" CssClass="navInnerDivContentsTopSubTwo">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibSave" ImageUrl="~/theImages/Save.png" runat="server" CssClass="navImages" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
                        <br />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnSave_Click" CssClass="linkOff" />
                    </asp:Panel>
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel94" runat="server" CssClass="navInnerDivContentsBottom">
                    Task Actions
                </asp:Panel>
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

code behind:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowMessage();
    if (CheckSameUser() == strUser)
    {
        UpdatePanel upTDNotes = (UpdatePanel)ContentMain.FindControl("upTaskDetailRight");
        if (upTDNotes != null)
        {
            upTDNotes.Update();
        }
        //MessageBox.Show(lblTDNotes.Value);
        string strSaveQuery = @"{QUERY}";
        //MessageBox.Show(strSaveQuery);

        using (SqlConnection scConn = new SqlConnection(strMainConn))
        {
            try
            {
                scConn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSaveQuery, scConn);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Session["queryChanged"] = "Yes";
            }
            catch (Exception ce)
            {
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
    }
    Response.Redirect("YourTasks.aspx");
}

public void ShowMessage()
{
    string message = "Hello!";
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
    sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
    sb.Append("alert('");
    sb.Append(message);
    sb.Append("')};");
    sb.Append("</script>");
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
}
```

When I click the Save button, the alert isn't being displayed. I have ScriptManager already on the page but it still didn't work.

How can I modify my code so I am able to see the alert (or even a confirm) window on click on the link/image

Comment: So, what bit of that code is *supposed* to show an alert? Because the code as presented never calls it. Also, note these other problems 1) the *update mode is conditional* and 2) the page is always *redirected away from*.

Comment: could you not create a BasePage class and create a static method inside of it for example create a file named `BasePage.cs` in the 
Public class declaration do `public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page{ }` inside of there create a method like so 

        public static void ShowClientMessageDlg(string msg, string aValue, string redirect = "")
        {
            string msgFormat;
            msgFormat = string.Format(" {0}", aValue);
            msg = msg + msgFormat;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('" + msg + "');</script>");
        }

Comment: @DJKRAZE Heavens no, in WebForms! Much less inside an UpdatePanel.

Comment: works for me actually I just tested it..

Comment: @DJKRAZE Then it hasn't been tested in an equivalent situation. The result of an Partial (UpdatePanel) PostBack is *not* plain HTML and injecting into the stream [randomly] is just going to [randomly] break the entire WebForm/Render model.

Comment: actually it has because I use an update panel and it works quite fine perhaps he has something else going on

Comment: I have my UpdatePanel defined as follow `<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">` I do not use the ClientIDMode = Static either

Comment: I use ClientIDMode for CSS purposes only.

Comment: no problem but for test purposes there are so many ways to test the showing of javascript.. I have known that from past experience that if you have any PostBacks being done and the Page_Load is being called and there are any errors your Message will never display.. I would suggest debugging this more closely to see if you are getting what you truly expect

Comment: Oh I am getting what I truly expect as it is toward end of testing phase but just wanted to add the alert.

Comment: I also know from experience that Response.Redirect and `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write` have different affects meaning from the stand point or Response.Write for example.. I have zero issues using this and like I have stated I just tried this out with just putting this code in the Page_Load event and works nice `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(` based on the code example I have posted in my comment

Answer (score 3):

Cut down to its most basic level, your code says this:

```
ShowMessage();
if (CheckSameUser() == strUser)
{
    // Stuff
}
else
{
}
Response.Redirect("YourTasks.aspx");
```

So you set up the bit of javascript to be run ... and then you send an instruction down to the browser to redirect to the page "YourTasks.aspx".

The javascript was set up to render when your page was sent down to the browser ... but you are redirecting before your page can be rendered, so that javascript never reaches the browser, and therefore never executes.

If what you want is to have the message display on the client immediately on click, and then have the server go and do something (like save your data and then send you to a new page), your best bet would be to hook the javascript up to a client-side event, like the submission of the form.  You can do this easily with jQuery or even with basic javascript (although the update panel can complicate things a bit.)

Comment: There are at least two other problems, but I'll go with this as one solid reason.

Comment: If I am inside the `IF` block pr execute the ShowMessage(), shouldn't it display the alert before hitting the Response.Redirect?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge No. The redirect **obliterates** any of the rendered output that was *going* to be sent as the response - this includes anything from the SM/ScriptBlock. The JavaScript only runs *when* the client receives the HTML/script to do so (when the normal request completes with the UpdatePanel/HTML mix), which never occurs because of the redirect.

Comment: no the JavaScript Message will actually display correctly first then after the click of the message it will redirect